# Rainmeter - How to launch a period task

Tags: windows, widget

I've used geektool for mac and you can setup a process (like a script) to run every x number of seconds and then display the output (say an image).

I'm trying to do something similar with Rainmeter (windows) but can't seem to make sense of it.  Is there a simple way in a skin to have it run a system command every x seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=1000 
;Updates rainmeter every second

[MeasurePeriodCommand]
UpdateDivider=15 
;Runs every 15 seconds
Measure=Calc
OnUpdateAction=["ping"] 
;replace 'ping' with any command


;you can omit this meter
[MeterDumb]
Meter=String
Text="This is working!"
FontSize=50
```

For more information, see [OnUpdateAction](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual-beta/measures/general-options#OnUpdateAction)